# Java Application communicating with Video Game

Tags: java, input, middleware, awtrobot

I have a java application that takes data from a wireless device, connected via bluetooth and performs specific actions according to the data.

The intention is to have this application be a sort of middleware, the wireless device tells it what game to load and then what actions to perform, ie move forward, jump, look around.

At the moment this is all done by using the Robot class and emulating keypresses and mousemove events, while this works; what I want is to be able to load and interact with the game directly.

I'm not sure how my java application can load a game (.exe) and input commands as they come from the wireless device, will I just have to settle with the Robot class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your relevant code? Given that you're communicating with programmers: most of us prefer to read code instead of prose.